# Django No Reverse Match Error - Template Rendering

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm getting the following error when trying to render a template:

```
NoReverseMatch at /things/
Reverse for 'edit_things' with arguments '(u'<function generate at 0x10a970aa',)' and     
keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

In my template, the following works:

```
<a href="{% url add_thing %}" class="btn_plus">
```

But then I get an error here:

```
<td onclick="document.location = '{% url edit_thing thing.guid %}';" class="edit" id="edit_thing_{{ forloop.counter }}">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
```

We're not using:
{% load url from future %}. This is Django 1.4.

In my urls:

```
url(r'^edit_thing/(?P<thing_id>[\w_-]{1,32})/$', 'edit_thing', name='edit_thing'),
```

And the view looks like:

```
def edit_thing(request, thing_id):
```

Any ideas on what is going wrong? I can't understand why add_things works fine in the template, and it crashes as soon as it gets to edit_thing. Could it be that edit_thing takes an argument? I've tried everything on Stackoverflow, and have tried every combination of things (including load url from future, and so forth).

Here's my model:

```
class Thing(models.Model):
  guid = models.CharField(max_length=Guid.LENGTH, blank=True, null=True, unique=True, default=Guid.generate)

  class Meta:
  app_label = 'things'
```

Comment: Have you tried `{% url things:edit_thing thing.guid %}`? (assuming the name of your app is actually `things`)

Comment: Could you paste your thing model? Also, try {% url edit_thing thing_id=thing.guid %}

Comment: Okay, so I tried {% url things:edit_thing thing.guid %}, and that solves the issue.

Now the issue I'm getting is:

`u'things' is not a registered namespace`. I have `things` in my `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: What django version? It is better to `{% load url from future %}` and `{% url 'things:edit_thing' thing.gui %}`.

Comment: @Konrad try adding the namespace when you include them in your [URLConf](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces-and-included-urlconfs).

Comment: What does `{{ thing.guid }}` output ? it should **not** output something like `function ...`

Comment: @César, so now I added `url(r'^', include(app_urlpatterns, namespace='things'))` to my urls.py.

But now, I'm back to the same error:

`Reverse for 'edit_thing' with arguments '(u'<function generate at 0x10a970aa',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found`

My URL is `{% url 'things:edit_thing' thing.guid %}`, and now I use `{% load url from future %}`.

Comment: @jpic, this is all in the middle of a for loop, where I do: `{% for thing in things %}`

Comment: What is `thing.guid`? The error message implies it's some sort of method. Can you show the definition?

Comment: Maybe you need default=Guid.generate() in your model definition. I guess you need the result of the function and not the function itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change your model definition. Change the `default`:

```
class Thing(models.Model):
  guid = models.CharField(max_length=Guid.LENGTH, blank=True, null=True, unique=True, default=Guid.generate())

  class Meta:
      app_label = 'things'
```

You are getting a string representation of a function because you were passing the function itself:

```
'(u'<function generate at 0x10a970aa',)'
```

In other words:

```
>>> unicode(Guid.generate)
u'<function generate at 0x10a970aa'
>>> unicode(Guid.generate()) # This is what you need
u'Result'
```

That should do it

Comment: In the database, I had: 'function generate at 0x10a970aa' as the guid, which was causing it to break. Thanks!